# Wind River workbench autogenerated make file issue

Tags: wind-river-workbench

In my projects folder I have plenty of svn files and directories as my projects are connected to an svn server. The workbench default make file generator tries to build all the folders inside the project folder in a recursive manner. The problem is that it tries to build the svn files and folders as well which slows down the compliation time.
What should I change so that workbench will ignore everyting inside a .svn folder.

I'm using **workbench 3.3**

Answer (score 0):

`Right Click Project-> Properties->Build Targets`
Unfortunately the best you can do is turn off the recursive behaviour and choose every file individually.

[image: screenshot]

You might have better luck editing the `.wrmakefile` to skip the `.svn` directories instead.  Doing this though, won't stop Windriver Workbench from creating makefiles inside the .svn directories..